# Unable to set transparency with RGB in Php Functions

Tags: javascript, php, function, rgb, color-scheme

I cannot use transparency when using rgb format in function:

> "message": "Unable to read color rgb(0 0 1 / 50%)."

If I use normal color like #ffff or #000, it works.

I am using this function in adding a text watermark over images.:

```
public static function addwatermark( $name ) {
    $thumbnail = Image::make($name);
    $thumbnail->text('WATERMARKTEXT', 90, 50, function ($font) use ($thumbnail) {
        $font->file('public/watermarkfont.ttf');
        $font->color(rgb(0 0 1 / 50%));
    });
    $thumbnail->save($name)->destroy();
}
```

Reference: https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/how-to-add-watermark-text-on-images-laravel-8/

Comment: you mean, `rgb(,0, 0, 0)` is fine but not `rgb(0 0 1 / 50%)`?

Comment: @Amit Yes the same issue

Comment: Nothing in your code produces that error message. Where is this code sending its output to?

Comment: And where does the `Image` come from? `Image` isn't a class built-in to PHP, so it must come from some package somewhere.

Comment: @KimHallberg `Image` is coming from a different controller

Comment: Well the error is coming from `Image#color` so we kinda need to see that too, but I would hazard a guess that whatever controller you are using doesn't support that syntax of colour.

Comment: Ok, but we cannot see the method `color` that you pass  `color_inverse` into, and since we don't know what the `Image` class does or how it handles colors we cannot do much atm.

Comment: @KimHallberg reference: https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/how-to-add-watermark-text-on-images-laravel-8/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to add opacity to `rgb()` when you want to use `rgba()`, that has the alpha channel that handles the opacity.

```php
public static function color_inverse($color){
    $color = str_replace('#', '', $color);
    if ($color == '000000'){ 
        return "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"; 
    }
    return "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
}
```

Here you can find all the formats available to the watermark `color` method in the [documentation](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/formats).

The opacity is from `1` to `0`, with `1` being 100%, and `0` being 0%, so `0.5` is 50% opacity.